# Valid GUID string gives Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'System.Guid'

Tags: c#, guid, typeconverter, iconvertible, changetype

I'm running the following code:

```
var guidStr = "C105534D-E001-46F1-874A-322E5E0E132C";
var guid1 = Guid.Parse(guidStr);
var guid2 = Convert.ChangeType(guidStr, typeof(Guid));
Console.WriteLine(guid1 + " " + guid2);
```

And while `guid1` is getting a value just fine, `guid2` line throws an exception:

```
Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'System.Guid'.
at System.Convert.DefaultToType(IConvertible value, Type targetType, IFormatProvider provider)
at System.String.System.IConvertible.ToType(Type type, IFormatProvider provider)
at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType)
```

What is the difference?

Unfortunately I'm using a given `dll` that fails on the second parsing, so cannot really change the implementation, only my input.

Comment: The `IConvertible.ToType` implementation for `String` (invoked from `Convert.ChangeType`) delegates to a generic conversion function (`DefaultToType`) that does not support `String` to `Guid`, unfortunately. You won't be able to use `Convert` for this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Guid.Parse` takes a string and interprets the string value into a `Guid` object. `Convert.ChangeType` attempts to directly change the string instance itself into a `Guid`.

Imagine the difference as being between reading a recipe from a cookbook to make a meal and trying to turn the cookbook itself into dinner.

Comment: Anything I can do over the input to make this call succeed?

Comment: @Mugen What is your input? What parts of the program are you required to use, and which do you have control over?

Comment: I have a module that gets input in a csv file and uses this functionality to import it to a TSQL DB, when reading the file, each element is cast from `String` to the matching SQL type, in this case `Guid` (`uniqueidentifier`)